# Drag and drop images using two datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, datalist

I have two data list one datalist have images. i want to drag those images and drop in another data list throught javascript or jquery. please help me. 
I checked 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dragdrop/dd-reorder.html 
link but it is not useful for me because they are using yahoo library for it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look into [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com).

In particular, I think that the [sortable component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) does what you want. The text items shown in the example can also be images.